# Redirect Failing on CORS Request

Tags: javascript, redirect, cors, box, preflight

I'm trying to download a file in client-side Javascript using the Box API, which redirects the request to a temporary download link once the file has been found.  The browser is blocking the redirect, though, throwing the following error:

**XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.box.com/2.0/files/file-id/content. The request was redirected to 'https://dl.boxcloud.com/d/1/some-big-hash/download', which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight.**

In the Network console I see three requests, the first is an OPTIONS (which must be the pre-flight because the actual code sends a GET) with a 200 response, and the second two are identical GET requests which both get 302'd (the expected response for that API call).  Here's the code that makes the request:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', url);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '+MyToken);
xhr.onload = function()
{
    //some stuff
}
xhr.onerror = function()
{
    //some other stuff
}
xhr.send();
```

My question is (a): Why are two GETs being sent after the preflight comes back?
And (b): Is there any way I can format the request to allow following the redirect?  And (c) if not, can I at least retrieve the redirect URL from the response and follow it with another explicit request?  Every response in the console has the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header set with the correct origin.

Thanks

Comment: `second two are identical GET requests` - everything identical?

Comment: @Maximus the request/response headers are identical, the only difference I can see is in the 'initiator' column of the Chrome network console; one says "https://api.box.com/2.0/files/file_id/content" (the URL to which the initial request is sent) and the other says "Other"

Comment: and the url is the same?

Comment: Yep (don't mind this need to hit min char limit)

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why you get three rather than two requests, but the way CORS has worked thus far is that a request with a preflight cannot be redirected. This has changed in the Fetch Standard, but user agents have not yet picked up the change.

Comment: Any idea why a preflight is required here in the first place?  Is 'Authorization' considered a custom header?

Comment: Yes, when you set it yourself it definitely is. https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-safelisted-request-header has the safelist of headers that do not require a preflight.